# workspace preview generate 404 page not found in typo3 version 7.6.4 LTS

Tags: php, typo3, workspace, typo3-7.x

I have tried to open page preview link by right click in backend (view page) in different workspace other than live worspace in typo3 but it generate wrong link (404 page not found), in typo3 version 6.2 it is working fine.

Please share here if you have any idea regarding this.

[image: Workspace preview generate 404 page not found]

Comment: 7.4 is not the LTS. Please upgrade to latest 7.6 and check again.

Comment: sorry, it is 7.6.4 LTS.